# Dynamic condition for reading XML path via XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

```html
<Document >
<Documentdate>"2019"</Documentdate>
<Order size="2">
  <Title>abc</Title>
  <Price>10</Price>
  <date>"2019"</date>
 </Order>
 <Order size="2">
  <Title>xyz</Title>
  <Price>20</Price>
  <date>"2018"</date>
 </Order>
 <Order size="4">
  <Title>Harry</Title>
  <Price>10</Price>
  <date>"2017"</date>
 </Order>
 </Document>
```

I need to use Xpath and read the orders that the date element is equal to Documentdate. I write in this way but it is not correct

```
/Document/Order[date = '../Documentdate']
```

Can anyone help me how can I set condition based on another element?

thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing it to the *string* `'../Documentdate'`, not the node value. Use:

```
/Document/Order[date = ../Documentdate]
```

Comment: Nice.`//Order[date=preceding::Documentdate]`should work too.